# Есть ли типы данных побольше double в студии?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio, c++

double и long double имеют одинаковый размер.

Однако doublе не подходит для работы со средними данными.
Там, где начинаются миллионы и миллиарды, double впадает в это 3.0546e-005.

1. Нужно, чтобы тип мог работать с миллиардами.
2. Быть очень быстрым, не таким, как библиотеки длинной арифметики, которые используют строки, могут работать с числами гугл длины, но при этом жутко медленные.
3. Повторял механику типа double. То есть был бы тип double_64, например, как у int_64, int_128 и т.д.

У меня идёт расчёт и получается число, например, 3421001.5422, но double его так не сможет вывести на экран. Как можно решить проблему? Только округляя значения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужен не другой тип данных, а просто изучать, как менять способ вывода чисел с плавающей точкой на С++. 3.0546e-005 - это экспоненциальная нотация, означает буквально следующее: 3.0546 * (10 в степени -5), т.е. явно не миллионы или миллиарды, а очень даже наоборот: 0.000030546.

Сам по себе double с миллиардами вполне справляется. Насколько я помню, в double можно без потери точности положить просто знаковое целое число до 2 в 53 степени, а это около 9*(10 в степени 15).

Вот здесь можно почитать, как вывести число в более привычной вам нотации:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/

В качестве бонуса, пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double a = 3421001.5422;
    std::cout << std::fixed << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
3421001.542200
```

http://ideone.com/gbkLdR

Comment: Да fixed помогло. Он когда нужна повышенная точность отбрасывает дробь. Для преобразования double в строку использую std::ostringstream.

    double a = 34224100657560076.54280082;  
    cout << 34224100657560076.000000   // -- то что выводится

Comment: @manking, а что за задача такая, где нужна подобная точность? Если не секрет, конечно.

Comment: Деньги в игре. В некоторых случаях при продолжительной игре возможен рост бюджета(или с читами) до миллиардов и выше. А они выводятся в разных местах, отчётах, таблицах и иногда туда попадала такая нотация, нечитабельная. 

Сейчас сделал так:

<< std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)  << sum;

Comment: @manking, думаю, совокупный ВВП в долларах всех стран Земли меньше, чем может уместиться в double. Если пишете игру, то делайте ограничение на максимально допустимое количество денег.

По поводу числа 34224100657560076.54280082: во-первых, зачем вам больше двух знаков после запятой? Во-вторых, сделайте ограничение на количество денег до 1e+14, тогда и копейки/центы поместятся.

Answer (score 2):

Тип double для денег - сумасшествие. Деньги надо хранить как целое число центов/копеек/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, вам подойдет long double - 12-байтовый.

Я вообще для расчетов использую библиотеку [Armadillo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armadillo_%28C%2B%2B_library%29).

Comment: long double в visual такой же, как и double, а доп. библиотеки не хочется подключать, и так отключил gmp и mpir.

Comment: Реализуйте вручную свой тип как вариант.

Но я все же рекомендую использовать матлибу, т.к. вы сэкономите время, нервы и силы.